# What is xfce4-indicator doing with over 1GB of my RAM?

Tags: linux, memory, process, xfce, xfce4

I noticed that xfce4-indicator is using up 24% of my RAM (I have 6GB). What's going on here?

For comparison, Firefox is using up 18%, and I have a ton of tabs open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug, please report this on XFCE forums: http://forum.xfce.org/

Comment: An update made it go away, but I'll come back to this if it happens again.